# Regex matching parentheses with =

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to filter out parameters of a handlebars call:

example call:

```
  117-tooltip classes=(concat (concat "productTile__product-availability " classes) " tooltip--small-icon productAvailability__tooltip") bla=(concat "test" "test2")
```

what my matches should be:

- classes=(concat (concat "productTile__product-availability " classes) " tooltip--small-icon productAvailability__tooltip")
- bla=(concat "test" "test2")

what my matches currently are:

- (concat (concat "productTile__product-availability " classes) " tooltip--small-icon productAvailability__tooltip")
- (concat "test" "test2")

my regex:

```
\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)
```

I need to extend it so the structure must be something=(...(...)..) with an unknown number of matching parentheses.

How do I need to extend the regex to get the x= part also into it?

Comment: Use [`(\w+)=(\((?>[^()]++|(?2))*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/zdnmSe/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [**regex subroutine**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html):

```php
(\w+)=(\(((?>[^()]++|(?2))*)\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zdnmSe/2). **Details**:

- `(\w+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more word chars
- `=` - a `=` char
- `(\(((?>[^()]++|(?2))*)\))` - Group 2 (needed for the regex subroutine to work):

  - `\(` - `(` char
  - `((?>[^()]++|(?2))*)` - Group 3: zero or more repetitions of one or more chars other than `(` and `)` or the whole Group 2 pattern recursed
  - `\)` - a `)` char.

Comment: thanks very much, this seems to work well in my test! How would I have to rewrite this to use it in Javascript? Seems like the ? and ++ is making problems

Comment: @NthDegree There is no way to use it JavaScript, its `RegExp` does not support recursion. Use Tim's solution in JS.

Answer (score 3):

I would use:

```regex
\b\w+=.*?(?=\s+\w+=|$)
```

### Demo

The idea behind this pattern is to match a key= followed by all content leading up to, but not including, either the next key, or the end of the input.

Explanation:

```
\b\w+=         match a KEY=
.*?            match all content up, but not including
(?=\s+\w+=|$)  assert that what follows is one or more
               whitespace characters followed by KEY= OR
               the end of the input
```